# Growth of iron crystals

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, geophysics, metals

What determines how large a crystal of iron will grow when heat and pressure are applied?

I was thinking about the Earth's core. Some have postulated that a large iron crystal is at the center of the core, and I was wondering if it could grow, or would other surrounding crystals hold the center crystal to a size.